# Swift Firestore - TableView Button Bug

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

[image]

Please look at my TableView with custom Cell here. I fetched the data from Firestore (and sort it by date descendingly) real time and insert it into the meal array locally. When I clicked the 'eat' button and add a new meal, the 'eat' button isn't sorted correctly?

Here is my code for loadMenu() function and eatButtonPressed() function

**loadMenu()**

```
 func loadMenu() {
        
        let menuRef = db.collection("menu").document()
        
        db.collection("menu").order(by: "date", descending: true).whereField("family_id", isEqualTo: "\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "family_id")!)")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                self.menu = []
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                
                let name = documents.map { $0["name"] ?? [""] }
                let family_id = documents.map { $0["family_id"] ?? [0] }
                let portions = documents.map { $0["portions"] ?? [""] }
                let menu_id = documents.map { $0["menu_id"] ?? [""]}
                let isOpened = documents.map { $0["isOpened"] ?? [""]}
                
                if name != nil || name[0] as! String != "" {
                    for i in 0..<name.count {
                        self.menu.append(Menu(menu_id: menu_id[i] as! String, name: name[i] as! String, family_id: family_id[i] as! String, portions: portions[i] as! Int, isOpened: isOpened[i] as! Bool))
                    }
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    }
```

**eatButtonPressed()**

```
 func eatButtonPressed(cell: TopPartTableViewCell, send: UIButton) {
        var likeRef = self.db.collection("like").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)_\(self.menu[send.tag].menu_id)")
        
        self.db.collection("dislike").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)_\(self.menu[send.tag].menu_id)").delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
            }
        }

        likeRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                self.db.collection("like").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)_\(self.menu[send.tag].menu_id)").delete() { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document successfully removed!")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                likeRef.setData([
                    "like_id": "\(likeRef.documentID)",
                    "user_id": "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)",
                    "menu_id": "\(self.menu[send.tag].menu_id)"
                ]) { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document successfully written!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        let user_liked = like.contains(where: {$0.menu_id == menu[send.tag].menu_id}) && like.contains(where: {$0.user_id == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid})
        
        if !user_liked {
            send.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BrandOrange")
            send.tintColor = UIColor.white
            
            cell.dontEatButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.dontEatButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        } else {
            send.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            send.tintColor = UIColor.black
            
        }
    }
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: not clear what is the question here, you have 1: `...TableView with Button Error Index` but then 
is it about sorting, 2: `...the 'eat' button isn't sort correctly?`
If 1:, show the error and what line of the code you have it. If 2: where do you sort the 
`menu`? Also make sure there is enough code to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine the sorting is in `db.collection("menu").order(by: "date", descending: true)`

Comment: I see, but you don't use `loadMenu()` in your `eatButtonPressed` function. Do you use it somewhere else after the `eatButtonPressed` is called?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine i use the loadMenu() in my viewDidLoad()

Comment: so it is sorted when you first do `viewDidLoad()`, but not after that, like after you press the `eatButtonPressed`, is that correct?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine no... even the `loadMenu()` is in `viewDidLoad()` , it always updated in every time we make changes inthe firestore

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is based on the screen capture and your question. What is happening that shouldn't and what should happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

The above method doesn't seem to be relevant to the question.

You have added a new item and a cell has been added for that item.

If you look at the detailed structure of the cell, I think you can figure out the cause.

If the cell default button state is Eat, it is most likely not initialized properly.